# Como evitar que se limpie un FileUpload cuando ocurre un evento en el formulario?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un fileUpload y un botón de la siguiente manera:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Cada vez que se genera el evento Click del botón se limpia el FileUpload, para evitar que el archivo seleccionado se borre lo estoy tratando de hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
               <Triggers>
              <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
          </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Supongo que debo incluir algo que desconozco en el Code Behind por el momento está así:

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then

        ' Código

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Pones como etiqueta C#, pero, ¿no te estarías refiriendo a VB?

Comment: Tienes razón, me equivoque por que el ejemplo que incluyo esta en VB, Disculpas...

Comment: Este enlace le puede servir https://forums.asp.net/p/1173651/1971535.aspx#1971535